# Plotting a star in a 2D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Do you know how can I get the following star marker when plotting a 2D plot?

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}


\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[ 
    width=\linewidth,
    line width=0.5,
    grid=major, % Display a grid
    tick label style={font={\tiny }},
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}},
    label style={font={\tiny }},
    legend image post style={},
    grid style={white},
    xlabel={$L$},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2
    },
    legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
    ]
    \addplot[yellow!70!black,mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
1.10513572361827
1.01208437057981
0.982129141362504
0.965535272773208
0.957525450047405
0.950991908467125
0.946662138047365
0.943677368384648
0.940827823053617
0.93852695585576
0.937338147322294
0.936376782449026
0.935476555754726
0.934912595379137
0.934178228940874
0.933667194443903
0.933013501708987
0.93258158463199
0.932380922764795
0.932389541141296
0.932133711215744
0.931961231250164
0.931738224344107
0.931468313557695
0.931422476255418
0.931391659490055
0.931455259106802
0.93149001089855
0.931437474580863
0.931450423300504
0.931455524207492








    };
    \addlegendentry{Pearson} 
    \addplot[black,mark=star] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
1.10719721735896
1.01582510540871
0.985098421134354
0.96786252360382
0.958886724738097
0.952042896687217
0.947384236080908
0.944073525331402
0.942432710350078
0.941273030120187
0.939938038398727
0.939550221948232
0.938367614513753
0.937633178953075
0.937095821198273
0.936939991272534
0.936277616991041
0.936242747915614
0.935844591009396
0.935483558286952
0.935277656644467
0.935123081220845
0.93485985632522
0.934528594943281
0.934930752987058
0.935051236286854
0.935076947538366
0.934886531636357
0.934947666897746
0.935073906674002
0.935157289426046







    };\addlegendentry{Cosin} 
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
  width=\linewidth,
  line width=0.5,
  grid=major, % Display a grid
  tick label style={font={\tiny \normalsize}},
  legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}},
  label style={font={\tiny }},
  legend image post style={},
  grid style={white},
  xlabel={$L$},
ylabel={RMSE},
   y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2
 },
legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
  ]
    \addplot[yellow!70!black, mark=*] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
1.10044666987188
0.999866628197923
0.962963949342376
0.943403150588027
0.931529691648424
0.924045339875979
0.918468987434381
0.913649154735605
0.911157563271859
0.908218682496785
0.906511033860998
0.90443746348175
0.903400003992971
0.902483106259459
0.901182138357611
0.901091293199105
0.899933357494439
0.900063989150366
0.899211759220085
0.898987646719118
0.898646916828567
0.898417264469362
0.898459860253319
0.897422113091948
0.897511433364885
0.897719097814211
0.897468138957815
0.896900763109816
0.896830721469015
0.896639819945792
0.896921589458794
0.896692907982105
0.896299668842855
0.896548805770678
0.896705444236237
0.896480855030312
0.896121426498849
0.896576004074635
0.896724593958936
0.896074079674064




};
\addlegendentry{Pearson} 
\addplot[black,mark=diamond*] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
1.1004034632523
0.998981366476003
0.964639819737259
0.9444588045967
0.934183872252177
0.926891588816588
0.920490355844599
0.916942125511546
0.914143090761063
0.91128589816521
0.909182330912049
0.908232246881679
0.906636708328323
0.905496628641986
0.904497783904894
0.903924914963062
0.902914066101777
0.903344661657377
0.902240953590319
0.901749031200971
0.901834063495761
0.901292603319992
0.90158539067463
0.90035948553436
0.900803164231954
0.900580586971413
0.900133521878354
0.900192476497936
0.899895224347253
0.900483176538678
0.900294084681683
0.899855113311963
0.900250507629163
0.899975977846179
0.899925759050512
0.90002961631342
0.900017002057276
0.900060834589157
0.899758520687127
0.900630302682763




};\addlegendentry{Cosine} 
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


    \subcaption{}

\end{subfigure}



\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You may use `\pgfdeclareplotmark` with some PGF commands for example...

Comment: I tried the basic ones from the pgf/tikz manual that are on the web. You have the pentagon, oplus*, diamond* etc, but, when I tried the star that’s on the manual, I could not get that wonderful design that’s on the picture :(

Comment: Please add what you've tried

Comment: Kay, i’ll do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do this for example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
          inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=mystar,red,dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (3,4) (4,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you get those skills from? Don't tell that the manual is complete enough ;)

Comment: @Delan I am going to tell that

Comment: Things are not going well with the corresponding legend entry?